# How to refer to parent object in jq walk?

Tags: json, jq

I have some json that I want to add to based on a walk. A simple example of the json I have is below:

```
{
  "valueSource": "memory",
  "dataType": "Boolean",
  "alarms": [
    {
      "setpointA": 1.0,
      "name": "Alarm",
      "priority": "Diagnostic",
      "ackMode": "Auto",
    }
  ],
  "name": "Test Alarm",
  "value": false,
  "tagType": "AtomicTag"
}
```

I want to add to each object in the "alarms" key's array the following key:

```
{
   "bindType": "Tag",
   "value": "[.]<parent.name>.Name"
}
```

where `<parent.name>` is "Test Alarm" in this example which is the parent-of-the-alarm-array-item's "name" key.

I've gotten this jq filter so far that adds the object, but the `value` key value is wrong (it's getting the alarm array item's name instead of its parent's name):

```
walk( if type == "object" and .setpointA then .label = {"bindType":"Tag", "value": "[.]\(.name).Name"} else . end)
```

Essentially I want this:

```
{
  "valueSource": "memory",
  "dataType": "Boolean",
  "alarms": [
    {
      "setpointA": 1.0,
      "name": "Alarm",
      "priority": "Diagnostic",
      "ackMode": "Auto",
      "label": {
        "bindType": "Tag",
        "value": "[.]Test Alarm.Name"
      }
    }
  ],
  "name": "Test Alarm",
  "value": false,
  "tagType": "AtomicTag"
}
```

Here is my jqplay below. It has the final result in the JSON section, where the Result should match this but doesn't at the moment.
https://jqplay.org/s/-qHFIWolrD

Follow up question:
How would I add this `displayPath` key as well?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reference to parent, you have to save the reference in a variable beforehand, and descend with having access to that variable.

```
.tags[] |= (
  .name as $name
  | # rest of your code using $name
    walk(
      if type == "object" and .setpointA
      then .label = {"bindType":"Tag", "value": "[.]\($name).Name"}
      else . end
    )
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Oqo-LhO-WG)

As you happen to know that the objects are located in the `.alarms` array, you could also just iterate over the items, `select` only those matching the condition and then assign to their `.label` whatever you want (including `$name`)

```
.tags[] |= (
  .name as $name
  | (.alarms[] | select(has("setpointA"))).label = {
      bindType: "Tag", value: "[.]\($name).Name"
    }
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/A3Z6LbW4qy)

---

Edit responding to OP's follow-up question

> I actually don't care about the `setpointA` key, I just want to add the `label` key (as well as another `displayPath` key) to each item in all `alarms` arrays.

```
.tags[] |= (.name as $name | .alarms[] += (
  {bindType: "Tag", value: "[.]\($name)."} | {
          label: (.value += "Name"),
    displayPath: (.value += "Documentation")
  }
))
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fYtyBICHle)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had the time to learn jq yet... In your second example, I actually don't care about the `setpointA` key, I just want to add the `label` key (as well as another `displayPath` key) to each item in all `alarms` arrays. How would I modify this to exclude the setpointA requirement and add the second displayPath key?

Comment: nevermind I got it
`.tags[] |= (.name as $name | .alarms[].label = {bindType: "Tag", value: "[.]\($name).Name"} | .alarms[].displayPath = {bindType: "Tag", value: "[.]\($name).Documentation"})`

Comment: @njminchin You can avoid iterating twice over `.array` by factoring it out: `.tags[] |= (.name as $name | .alarms[] | .label = {bindType: "Tag", value: "[.]\($name).Name"} | .displayPath = {bindType: "Tag", value: "[.]\($name).Documentation"})`. I also updated my answer which further factors out `{bindType: "Tag", value: "[.]\($name)."}`

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks again, this has really helped with my understanding of jq :)

Answer (score 2):

As jq does not allow you to refer to parent object, you need to work on parent level :

```
jq 'walk(if type == "object" and .alarms and ( .alarms | arrays )
         then (.alarms[] | select(.setpointA)).label =
                    { bindType: "Tag", value: "[.]\(.name).Name"}
         else . end
    )' data.json
```